# Powershell - Set list item in json

Tags: json, powershell

I have the following json file.

```
{
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": "Information",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console",
      "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    } 
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "logs/log.txt",
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
      "formatter": {
        "type": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
      },
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 104857600
    }
  }
],
"Properties": {
  "Application": "Serilog Demo"
  }
 },
}
```

The powershell script I'm using is like this:

```
    function update_ConnStr{

param (
    [string]$jsonFile
    )
$a = Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection = "server=$($updServer);port=$($updPort);database=$($updDatabase);uid=$($updUid);password=$($updPwd)"
($a | ConvertTo-Json -depth 10 ) -replace "\\u0027", "'" | Out-File -FilePath $jsonFile
}
$updServer=$env:DATABASE_HOST
$updPort=$env:DATABASE_PORT
$updDatabase=$env:DATABASE_NAME 
$updUid=$env:DATABASE_USERNAME 
$updPwd=$env:DATABASE_PASSWORD

update_ConnStr("..\src\s----\appsettings.Production.json");
```

I'd like to modify the logs path - something like -
$a.Serilog.WriteTo[2].Args.path

I'll appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: Arrays in .NET (and by extension, in PowerShell) are _0-indexed_, so the 2nd item in an array will have index **1**, eg. `$a.Serilog.WriteTo[1].Args.path = ...`

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `getDataType $myDate` - _not_ like C# methods - `getDataType($myDate)`.  It happens to work with a _single_ argument, but breaks with multiple ones, because if you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.